# Rename values in a column of df1 referencing a table in df2

Tags: recode

I want to recode values in a column of df1 by referencing a second df. My data currently look like this:

df1 contains the data and the variable names I need to recode:

ID   Variable    Data
1    X_Q1_1      15
2    X_Q1_2      2
3    X_Q2_1      27
4    Y_Q2_2      7

df2 contains the current variable names and the names I want to change them to:

Old_Variable  New_Variable
X_Q1_1        Fred_Cars_1
X_Q1_2        Fred_Cars_2
X_Q2_1        Fred_Bikes_1
Y_Q2_2        Ginger_Bikes_2

Is there a way to recode these variable names in df1 by referencing the names in df2?

I know how to do this by recoding them one variable name at a time, but can't find a good way to do it by referencing the table. Looking for a tidyverse answer, if possible.